# using javascript data in php error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Using this ajax code i am passing data speedMbps  from my javascript to php.
however when i tried to use the speedMbps in php i am getting a Undefined index: speedMbps. what should i do so i can use speedMbps in php?

Edited: video_id is send using html form post.

```
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "viewvideo.php",
          data: {speedMbps: speedMbps },
          cache: false
        }).done(function( html ) {
            $( "#speed" ).val( html );
    });
```

php file

```
if(isset($_POST['video_id']) && ( $_POST['speedMbps'] )){
$speed = $_POST['speedMbps'];
if ($speed < 100) {

                }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending `video_id` with AJAX request?

Comment: video_id is send using html form.

Comment: its not being sent simultaneously.. since u r making an ajax request

Comment: so how should i do it? since i need to get the video_id too.

Comment: If you are having multiple form fields or both of this fields are part of same form then use [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "viewvideo.php",
          data: {"speedMbps" : speedMbps,"video_id":video_id },
          cache: false
        }).done(function( html ) {
            $( "#speed" ).val( html );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

here you checking two varibales with `AND` condition but passing only one variable. so you can change `AND` condition to `OR` and try it.

```
if(isset($_POST['video_id']) || isset( $_POST['speedMbps'] )){  //missing isset function here. also change AND to OR
```

Or you have to pass video_id also in ajax function like this:

```
 data: {speedMbps: speedMbps, video_id:video_id },
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put speedMbps in single quotes.

```
data: {'speedMbps': speedMbps },
```

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Comment: yes, It tells JS and PHP that you want the variable speedMbps to be mapped to the key "speedMbps"

Comment: `speedMbps: speedMbps` also does the same thing

Comment: You only need to check speedMbps in php file. You are mapping only the variable speedMbps. 
if(isset( $_POST['speedMbps'] ){

Answer (score 0):

You either need to send `video_id` with AJAX request or you can remove the condition in php and check since in php you are checking if `video_id` is set or not, `if(isset($_POST['video_id']) && ( $_POST['speedMbps'] )){`

```
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "viewvideo.php",
          data: {
            speedMbps: speedMbps,
            video_id:  VIDEO_ID_PUT_HERE //`video_id: $('[name="video_id"').val()`
          },
          cache: false
        }).done(function( html ) {
            $( "#speed" ).val( html );
    });
```

in your php:

```
if(isset($_POST['video_id']) && isset($_POST['speedMbps'] )){
  $speed = $_POST['speedMbps'];
   if ($speed < 100) {
   //do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: how do i send my form. code in jsfiddle using ajax?https://jsfiddle.net/9wpg0993/1/

Comment: `video_id: $('[name="video_id"').val()`

Comment: Just notice that ajax is expecting a response on $( "#speed" ).val( html ); and i am planning to do embed the html 5 video in php file but i dun think that will work.. any suggestion on how to implement embed video after getting both the speed and video_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
var speedMbps ='' //here is Your value for speedMbps
var videoid = //here  is Your value for video id    
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "viewvideo.php",
          data: {speedMbps: speedMbps ,videoid:videoid},
          cache: false,
       success:(function( html ) {
            $( "#speed" ).val( html );
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "viewvideo.php",
      data: {speedMbps: "speedMbps" },
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $( "#speed" ).val( html );
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This will post the string `speedMbps` to the PHP script instead of the variable content.